# Sass lightness() function not working with TailwindCSS theme variables

Tags: sass, tailwind-css

I have a colour Sass map of project themes to give me the opportunity to loop and generate class options (e.g. `.row--primary` and `.row--secondary` etc) without having to manually specify them with Tailwind's variables. These are defined as follows:

```
$colors: (
    'primary':      theme('colors.green.700'),
    'secondary':    theme('colors.red.500'),
);
```

Then with my `.row` partial, I can do this:

```
.row {
    @each $name, $hex in $colors {
        &--#{$name} {
            background: $hex;

            // Setting the text colour based on how dark/light the bg is.
            color: set-text-color($hex);
        }
    }
}
```

In here, there is a function that utilises the Sass lightness function so I can automate having dark or light text depending on the background:

```
@function set-text-color($color) {
    @if (lightness($color) > 80) {
        @return color('black');
    } @else {
        @return color('white');
    }
}
```

But this is throwing the following: `Error: argument '$color' of 'lightness($color)' must be a color`.

I have tried a lot to resolve this. When I replace my theme map variables that use tailwind's variable (`theme('colors.green.700')`) with a basic hex, it works. Is there any way around this so I can still access the TailwindCSS variable?

Comment: It means that `theme('colors.green.700')` is not a color. Try to `@debug` it and see what it returns. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/debug

Comment: The debugger is outputting `DEBUG: color: theme("colors.orange.500")`. So it's not getting the Tailwind variable associated with the function, but just rendering it as is.

Comment: Yes, that's what I guessed. You unfortunately can't pull any "foreign" data with Sass.

Answer (score 3):

Tailwind is applied during the PostCSS phase which is **after** less, scss, sass processors. Because the theme() is a Tailwind function the value is NOT available during your preprocessor compilation.

This particular situation is explained further [in the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#using-sass-less-or-stylus).

I haven't tried this (but will soon), but you should be able to store your color values in a JSON file. Then import this file in SCSS using [this plugin](https://github.com/pmowrer/node-sass-json-importer). Then back in the `tailwind.config.js` import this JSON file and use the values from it. This would create a single source of truth for your values.